# Flutter how to convert a string to list using json decode in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the list below which I want to convert and store as a String so that when I need it later I will decode the string back to the list so I can use it as an argument.

```
 List allTasks = [
   {"project-name":"My First Project"},
   {"date-time":"12 Mar 2021Z 12:34:05 am"},
   {"people":["John","Doe"]},
   {"project-body":[
    {
     "id":"0",
     "color": Colors.transparent,
     "name":"hello amigo",
     "sub-children":[
       {
        "id":"0",
        "color": Colors.transparent,
        "type":"text",
        "state":"waiting",    
        "mediaUrl":"",             
         "name":"Heya its me",
         "hasMessage":false,
         "people":[
           {"person-id":"id110",
            "profile-pic":"",
           }
         ]
       },       
     ],
    },     
   ],
  }
 ];
```

**This code is used to store this in sharedPreference** First I convert the list to a string and then pass it.

```
  void storeValuesLocally(String mainlist)async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String myToJson = json.encode(mainlist);
  await prefs.setString('main-list', myToJson);  
  }
```

**Below I am trying to decode the string back to a list**

```
  void getAndSetTaskValues()async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String values = (prefs.getString('main-list') ?? [].toString());
  var castedToList = json.decode(values);
    print(castedToList[0].runtimeType); // String
  }
```

**My prblem**
Whenever I try to assign the decoded results to a list it throws an error. This is because `castedToList` is a string because when I check the type it's a string.
How do I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert it to string then encode it. Because decoding it will return a string as it's happening with you now.

Instead, encode the list as it is.

```
void storeValuesLocally(List mainlist)
```

Comment: With shared preferences you can not store `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was that,
`Colors.transparent` was not a json type so it could not be encoded or decoded.